# How to extract individual value from this string?

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, I have this input

```
'Templeton Primary School,Wantirna,VIC,3152\r\n                                    \r\n                                        3152\r\n                                    \r\n                                        98\r\n                                    \r\n                                        \r\n                                    \r\n                                        \r\n                                    696'
```

So from the input above, I will get:

address: Templeton Primary School,Wantirna,VIC,3152

postcode: 3152

score: 98

enrolNum: 696

I have something like this: `/(.+)(\\r\\n *)+(.+)(\\r\\n *)+(.+)(\\r\\n *)+(.+)/g`

Obviously, it is not working.

Comment: Does the structure of your data have any kind of consistency?

Comment: Each element is separated by (\\r\\n *)+

Comment: You may have a problem with cross-platform compatibility. Mac OS & Linux will give you just `\n`, not `\r\n`. Also, does your string have `\r\n` as text, or does it have line breaks?

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the string into an array, then you can access the specific parts you need.

```
var theList = your input data;
var address = theList.split(',');
var zip = address[3];
```

Also, how is your form set up to collect this data? One textbox is a bad design. Try splitting the fields up into separate text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^(.*?)\D+(\d+)[\D]+(\d+)\D+(\d+)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EZ1mCQ/5)

```js
const regex = /^(.*?)\D+(\d+)[\D]+(\d+)\D+(\d+)$/gm;
const str = `Templeton Primary School,Wantirna,VIC,3152\\r\\n                                    \\r\\n                                        3152\\r\\n                                    \\r\\n                                        98\\r\\n                                    \\r\\n                                        \\r\\n                                    \\r\\n                                        \\r\\n                                    696`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log("address: "+m[1]);
    console.log("postcode: "+m[2]);
    console.log("score: "+m[3]);
    console.log("enroll number: "+m[4]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, it is almost there. The input is exactly like the one in my question. While your input contain new lines.

Comment: But the thing is, \r\n indicates new line, i hope you are not asking me to escape new line or carriage return in the regex for you ... actually I can... but it doesn't seem appropriate to me ... is it ?

Comment: yes, you are right. My bad. /^(.*)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)$/ works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
var input= '''INPUT GOES HERE''';
var inputList = input.split('\\r\\n');
var address = inputList[0].trim();
var postcode = inputList[1].trim();
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 'Templeton Primary School,Wantirna,VIC,3152\r\n                                    \r\n                                        3152\r\n                                    \r\n                                        98\r\n                                    \r\n                                        \r\n                                    \r\n                                        \r\n                                    696'
var arr = str.split(',');

arr = arr.concat(/(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)$/.exec(arr.pop()).slice(1));

console.log( arr )

var result = {
    address : arr.slice(0,4).join(','),
    postcode: arr[4],
    score   : arr[5],
    enrolNum: arr[6]
};

console.log(result)
```